# Telegram Bot works with other accounts but it does not work with my account

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, rasa

I have developed a chatbot with Rasa Open Source and I have integrated it on Telegram. But when I tested it with my account it didn't work. I tested it with 3 other Telegram accounts and there it seems to work perfectly. When I try to interact with it from my account it throws the following errors and exceptions:

````
Exception occurred while handling uri: 'httpt/webhooks/telegram/webhook'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 931, in handle_request
    response = await response
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/telegram.py", line 228, in message
    if self._is_user_message(msg):
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/telegram.py", line 180, in _is_user_message
    return message.text is not None
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
Invalid response object for url b'/webhooks/telegram/webhook', Expected Type: HTTPResponse, Actual Type: <class 'NoneType'>
Exception occurred while handling uri: ngrok.io/webhooks/telegram/webhook'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/server.py", line 509, in write_response
    response.output(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'output'
Exception occurred while handling uri: 'ngrok.io/webhooks/telegram/webhook'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 931, in handle_request
    response = await response
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/telegram.py", line 259, in message
    await on_new_message(
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/channel.py", line 89, in handler
    await app.agent.handle_message(message)
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/agent.py", line 577, in handle_message
    return await processor.handle_message(message)
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/processor.py", line 108, in handle_message
    await self._predict_and_execute_next_action(message.output_channel, tracker)
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/processor.py", line 657, in _predict_and_execute_next_action
    action, prediction = self.predict_next_action(tracker)
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/processor.py", line 379, in predict_next_action
    prediction = self._get_next_action_probabilities(tracker)
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/processor.py", line 921, in _get_next_action_probabilities
    prediction = self.policy_ensemble.probabilities_using_best_policy(
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/policies/ensemble.py", line 817, in probabilities_using_best_policy
    winning_prediction = self._best_policy_prediction(tracker, domain, interpreter)
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/policies/ensemble.py", line 694, in _best_policy_prediction
    predictions = {
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/policies/ensemble.py", line 695, in <dictcomp>
    f"policy_{i}_{type(p).name}": self._get_prediction(
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/policies/ensemble.py", line 729, in _get_prediction
    prediction = policy.predict_action_probabilities(
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/policies/unexpected_intent_policy.py", line 576, in predict_action_probabilities
    is_unlikely_intent = self._check_unlikely_intent(
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/policies/unexpected_intent_policy.py", line 671, in _check_unlikely_intent
    if not self._should_check_for_intent(query_intent, domain):
File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/policies/unexpected_intent_policy.py", line 633, in _should_check_for_intent
    if domain.intents.index(intent) not in self.label_thresholds:
ValueError: 'hu' is not in list
Exception occurred while handling uri: '.ngrok.io/webhooks/telegram/webhook'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 931, in handle_request
    response = await response
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/telegram.py", line 228, in message
    if self._is_user_message(msg):
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/telegram.py", line 180, in _is_user_message
    return message.text is not None
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
Exception occurred while handling uri: 'http.ngrok.io/webhooks/telegram/webhook'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 931, in handle_request
    response = await response
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/telegram.py", line 228, in message
    if self._is_user_message(msg):
  File "/home/sanja/rasa-assistant-mbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/channels/telegram.py", line 180, in _is_user_message
    return message.text is not None
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'```
````

Comment: Can you add your code that handles the Telegram messages? Also, do you use a webhook or polling? (see https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks )

Comment: Hi, I am using a webhook. I assume you are referring to the code in the Telegram.py document that comes by default when a project is created in Rasa: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/main/rasa/core/channels/telegram.py